# The notion of a falling object

Tags: classical-mechanics

When an object falls down, it follows the $z$ axis. Then why do we describe the displacement using $y$ as $y(t)=y_0+v_0 t + \dfrac{1}{2} at^2$. Shouldn't we be using $z$ instead?

Comment: Why would it follow the z axis? In which direction do the x, y and z axes point?

Comment: Doesn't $z$ axis point upward and downward?

Answer (score 2):

You are the one who defines the coordinate system. There is no "universal coordinate system" prefixed. The parabolic movement made by a falling particle occurs in a plane. You could use a $xy$ plane where $y$ is the vertical axis and $x$ is the horizontal axis. The $z$ coordinate is not usually introduced in a movement that takes place in a plane. Now, if you had a three-dimensional coordinate system that is already fixed, then you should consider a system of three equations, one for each coordinate.

Comment: So when $y=0$ in $(x,y,z)$ we're left with $xz$ plane but we call it $xy$ plane instead. Is my assumption correct?

Comment: Consider the plane on which the parabolic movement is taking place. You can establish a coordinate system given by the axes $ x $ and $ y $, in which the positive orientation of $y$ points to the opposite direction to the gravitational force, and the positive orientation of $ x $ points to a direction perpendicular to $ y$ in the plane. Then the equation $ y(t) = y_0 + v_0t + \frac{1}{2}at^2$ is valid.

Answer (score 0):

Don't put too much power into the labeling of coordinate axes. You can choose whichever name you want.

- Usually, when only in 2D, we choose the y-axis upwards and the x-axis horizontal. In physics you will often tilt this, though, so they both point a bit at an angle.
- Usually, when in 3D, we choose the z-axis upwards and the x- and y-axes horizontal. But you can easily experience cases where people draw it up differently.

The point is that it doesn't matter - it can vary from case to case. So be sure you know what is done in a particular example, and don't worry about it not being equal to the labeling in other examples. Do a simple [Google Images search for "coordinate system"](https://www.google.dk/search?q=coordinate%20systems&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj6je_H5LzeAhWCo4sKHQtsCKsQ_AUIDigB&biw=1368&bih=722) and you'll see many varied examples, for instance the following:

[image] <sup>[source](https://docs.speedtree.com/doku.php?id=coordinate_systems)</sup>